# rubygems.org において、 yanked な gem とは？

Tags: ruby, rubygems

bootstrap-sass のバージョン一覧をみていました。 https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass/versions

その中に、 `yanked` と表示されるバージョンがあることに気がつきました。そして、該当バージョンは(ひとまず素直には) gem install できないっぽいな、と思っています。

#### 質問

rubygems において、 yanked な gem version とは一体何ですか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

間違えて公開(push)してしまった場合や、他の人がgem名を引き継ぐ時に備えた対応のようです。
(恒久的なファイルの削除ではなく、名前は予約したままファイルやバージョンを削除する？)

[Policy change about gem yank](https://blog.rubygems.org/2015/04/13/permadelete-on-yank.html)

> “Yanking” a gem was introduced as a way to remove a gem from the RubyGems.org index, usually because of an accidental gem push or someone wanting to allow others to take over the gem’s name.

Comment: 「rubygems.org のレポジトリから remove する機能が yank だよ」「s3 からの削除は、Versioning によって restore できるから、 remove を直接行うようにしたよ」ということですね。

Comment: 参考情報です：[バックドアを含むバージョンのbootstrap-sassパッケージがRubyGemsで見つかる](https://security.srad.jp/story/19/04/07/0053218/)

Comment: @nekketsuuu ヤベェやつだった